# Flutter Quill library not working with text widget? also html_editor_enhance not working fine with flutter 3:-

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, quill, flutter-android

my code is for Quill:-

```
import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart';

body:Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        const **Text**('category:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
        Text(widget.news.categoryName.toString(),
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
      ],
    ),
    QuillToolbar.basic(controller: _controller),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
      child: QuillEditor.basic(
        controller: _controller,
        readOnly: false, // true for view only mode
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

In code the Text widget gives error =>

> The name 'Text' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart' and 'package:flutter_quill/src/models/documents/nodes/leaf.dart (via package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart)'.

Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.

Answer (score 7):

This should solve the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart' hide Text;
```

the package 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart' is exporting something called "Text", this is having conflict with the Text from material.dart. Using the reserved word hide when importing flutter_quill will not import the Text from flutter_quill

Comment: it worked. could you explain this situation?

Comment: the package 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart' is exporting something called "Text", this is having conflict with the Text from material.dart.
Using the reserved word hide when importing flutter_quill will not import the Text from flutter_quill